# Dúvida em recebimento de dados

Tags: java

Tenho um sistema em um computador que enviará dados para outro sistema em outro computador. O sistema que receberá os dados precisará ficar lendo esses dados recebidos em tempo real e automático.

Mas minha dúvida em construir o sistema é de como posso fazer para ele saber em tempo real e automaticamente que recebeu os dados do outro sistema?

Utilizo java..

------------------ EDIT ------------------

Estou fazendo um projeto de TCC, um computador que ficaria no balcão do estabelecimento teria um programa que o usuário cadastra os pedidos das pessoas. Ai teria um botão de enviar o pedido, ai esse botão enviaria os dados do pedido para um computador que fica na cozinha do estabelecimento. Mas nesse computador da cozinha, seria um outro sistema que fica "escutando" a chegada destes pedidos, ou seja teria que ser automático para saber quando um pedido chegou.

Comment: Como você irá fazer o envio dos dados?

Comment: Bom estudo. http://www.devmedia.com.br/java-sockets-criando-comunicacoes-em-java/9465

Comment: Partindo do principio que será uma arquitetura cliente/servidor com um outro cliente lendo as informações, se foi o que entendi, você pode usar `Sockets / Threads` que irão ficar `ouvindo` para processar as informações.

Comment: Rodrigo, você quer uma indicação de tecnologia ou quer uma solução pronta para o seu problema? Esses sistemas já existem ou serão criados? Por quem? É um projeto acadêmico ou um sistema de verdade? Que tipos de dados serão transmitidos? Qual a natureza da comunicação? Precisa haver resposta? Poderia definir melhor o que seria "tempo real"? Quais ações o outro sistema precisa executar e qual o tempo de resposta esperado? Há algum risco se houver demora? Há possibilidade de haver eventos de comunicação executando simultaneamente?

Comment: Estou fazendo um projeto de TCC, um computador que ficaria no balcão do estabelecimento teria um programa que o usuário cadastra os pedidos das pessoas. Ai teria um botão de enviar o pedido, ai esse botão enviaria os dados do pedido para um computador que fica na cozinha do estabelecimento. Mas nesse computador da cozinha, seria um outro sistema que fica "escutando" a chegada destes pedidos, ou seja teria que ser automático para saber quando um pedido chegou.

Comment: @RodrigoLima Neste caso a solução mais fácil serve: o computador do balcão salva o pedido numa base de dados compartilhada e o software no computador da cozinha tem um timer que de tantos em tantos segundos verifica a base. Se para o TCC você precisa elaborar uma solução mais complexa, então é melhor inventar um problema mais complexo também, onde daí sim a solução poderia passar por socket ou sistema de filas de mensagens.

Comment: Entendi, poderia me citar um exemplo, de em que tipo de sistema o Socket pode ser usado?

Comment: @RodrigoLima Chat é um tipo de aplicativo que apesar de simples faz todo sentido usar socket. De quaquer modo eu não sei os objetivos ou critérios do TCC né. De repente aceitam o lance dos pedidos. Só que na vida real seria pouco provável investir numa solução mais complexa para isso do que simplesmente ficar checando a base. Outras opções (onde eu me lembro de já ter usado socket): monitoramento em "tempo real" de equipamentos industriais, notificação de atualização de estado em sistemas de terceiros, servidor de aplicativos proprietário, filas de mensagens entre sistemas...

Answer (score 1):

Em tempo real mesmo pode ser difícil, para não dizer impossível.
Algum atraso você deverá ter, já que tem a rede entre os computadores no meio.

A melhor forma de fazer a comunicação é uma arquitetura de cliente servidor mesmo, com um dos sistemas enviando e outro recebendo dados.
Em Java, vale a pena dar uma olhada em como funciona a parte de Sockets e de rede para mandar e receber pacotes em UDP ou TCP (padrão de comunicação com ou sem conexão).